# Owner of shared directory

Tags: files, permissions, directory, group

The directory `/path/to/dir` is meant to be used by *any* member of the group `examplegroup`. All the members of this group should be able to modify the content of the directory without limitations (read/write files, create files, run executables).

It is obvious that the group owner of the directory must be `examplegroup`.

But what could be an appropriate choice for the *user owner* of the directory? `root`, one of the users of the `examplegroup`, `nobody`, or someone else?

Comment: you can set `examplegroup` group ownership for your folder

Comment: The owner should be whoever is authorized to change permissions of the folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoever is the owner will be able to change permissions of the directory, which would allow him to remove the group-write permission. So it should be a user who is trusted with that ability. It could be the group leader, for instance. Or it could be someone outside the group if none of them are so trusted.

If you set it to `root`, then only system administrators will be able to change directory permissions. But if permissions never need to change, this shouldn't be a problem.